# displays search items even if there is !=

Tags: c#, asp.net

My website searches rhymes in dummy database. In the code, if textbox is != do the search, else, display error, however, it shows the results even if there is nothing in the search box. Why is that?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Clear();
        if (Page.PreviousPage != null)
        {
            TextBox SourceTextBox =
              (TextBox)Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("TextBox1");
            if (SourceTextBox != null)
            {
                cnn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT kelimeler FROM kelimelerim WHERE kelimeler LIKE @searchkey", cnn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchkey", "%" + SourceTextBox.Text);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(dr.GetString(0));
                    }
                }
                cnn.Close();
            }

            else
            {
                ListBox1.Items.Add("Lütfen bir harf giriniz");
            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Next time could you copy the code rather than provide images?

Comment: @JonoRR Thanks for suggestion. I replaced images with codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable SourceTextBox will never be null since the control is always rendered and submitted during posts. You need to check the text of the TextBox instead of the TextBox object to determine if any text has been entered.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(SourceTextBox.Text))
{
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking if the control exists.
Ofcourse it exists, you've created it.

You must check if the value of it is empty

Answer (score 0):

```
if (SourceTextBox != null)
{

}
```

To change this format

```
if (SourceTextBox.Text != null || !String.isNullorEmpty(SourceTextbox.Text))
{

}
```

Comment: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` does already check for null, so you don't need the first `SourceTextBox.Text != null` check